# problem with jquery form plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I have Jquery Form plugin but i do not have submit button in my form ? i have a checkbox and on its click i submit the form . The form gets submitted but without the ajax . I am wondaring if it is possible to use jquery form plugin with out a  submit button in it. ?

This is the code i am using for submitting the jquery form plugin using checkbox onlclick event. Every thing works fine without the onclick event.

```
$('#anl_popup').hide();
var options = { success: showResponse  // post-submit callback };

$('#favourite_form').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});

$('#remember_checkbox').click(function() {
    document.favourite_form.submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: yes, it don't care you have a button or not. maybe you should put your code here to let us know what's wrong with it.

Comment: i have edited and added the code i am using for submitting the form using checkbox on click

Comment: try to see firebug's console if you got some js error...

Comment: @user569403: You've commented out the closing brace of the `options` object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can submit your form without a submit button. 
I would suggest to write it like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#favourite_form').ajaxForm({ success: showResponse });
   $('#remember_checkbox').click(function() {
       this.form.submit();
   });
});
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText + 
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.'); 
}
```

That should be enough.